# jQuery - Parameters in load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

Is it possible to pass parameters through the load function when using it for multiple images?

```
var images = {0 : {target_ : 'url', foo : 'foo', bar : 'bar'}, 1 : {target_ : 'url',foo : 'baz', bar : 'qux'}};

for(var image in images){
   var x_ = image.foo;
   var y_ = image.bar;
   $(image.target_).load(function(){
    console.log(x_ + y_);
   });
}
```

Comment: Why don't you test it? Note that when you want to create a string value you should use quotes. `var x_ = 'foo';`

Comment: Sorry, edited my q. I'm using multiple images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can use the data attribute to store additional information's on image's.

And than you can do something like

```
$(image).load(function(){
    var x__ = $(this).data("x");
    var y__ = $(this).data("y");
});
```

While the img tag could be something like

```
<img src="#" data-x="someValx" data-y="someValy">
```

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be a option, but wont this slow down the script?